# Are morphisms between affine schemes the same?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Assume that $X,Y$ are affine schemes and $f,g\colon X\to Y$ morphisms between them. If the induced map $\mathrm{sp} (f),\mathrm{sp} (g)\colon\mathrm{sp} (X)\to\mathrm{sp} (Y)$ is the same(i.e. the induced map on the spectrum of these rings), are they the same morphisms? If not, are there any counter-examples?

Comment: No. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{F}_p[T]$, then both the maps $T \mapsto T^p$ and $T \mapsto T$ induce the identity map on the underlying topological spaces.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{F}_p[T]$, then both the maps $T \mapsto T^p$ and $T \mapsto T$ induce the identity map on the underlying topological spaces.

Comment: Similarly: any field automorphism, e.g. complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$.